# What does "This edit is too minor" mean?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, suggested-edits

I'm improving posts on Stack Overflow. I don't know why, but quite often someone votes to reject my suggested edit as "too minor" when I improved every issue in the post!

I cannot improve more if everything is improved. Do you think that [this is a "too minor" edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2584815)

I think it is not.

People who checking suggested edits should be more clever!

Comment: This is a borderline case; I see donovan has also rejected some of your other edits that were more minor than this edit. Your grasp of English grammar and spelling may be what is at stake here though. You may want to avoid improving grammar and spelling when your own language skills are still lacking.

Comment: @Ty221 - Not sure if it makes a difference, but the end result is that your edit was [approved](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2584815) by three other people.

Comment: I reject a lot of edits for being "too minor", and I would have approved this one. For whatever it is worth. I think you *do* make some substantive edits. Your grammar is better than the original, and the post is easier to read. Good enough for me.

Comment: I think your instincts about what in the post needed improvement is fine. If I had seen this in review I would have improved it with several additional changes (capitalization, mainly), improved _your_ grammar slightly and marked your edit as helpful.

Comment: @chuex Yes, I know that my edit has been approved, but it was only an example. A lot of people in a lot of my suggestions are voting to reject my edit as "too minor"

Comment: The truth is, it's subjective. There's no hard and fast rule about which edits are "too minor". Everyone has a little bit different standard. That's why, as in this case, votes are sometimes split between the reviewers. I discussed this and a few general guidelines in a bit more detail in [my answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186987/definitive-line-between-minor-and-substantial-edits).

Comment: Do we really need a screen shot of the very edit that is linked? If I edit it out, will that be too minor? :-)

Comment: Photo has been removed

Comment: Ah, much better, thank you!

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I added the link to the edit; I swithered between leaving the screenshot in and taking it out. I should have taken it out.

Comment: @MartijnPieters no worries. I just really didn't think it added anything, especially since you could barely read the words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your description is important. Just "some small edits" is not clear for what you suggest to change in the question.

You added a new `tag`, why you did that is important to write on your edit. Besides the tag issue, the edits you did were not essential. Editing and changing is justified if to correct a very bad English or a question that was difficult to understand.

I would accept your edit because it makes the question better. This is of course personal.

**"This edit is too minor"** means the reviewer thought your changes in the post are not enough, in quantity and/or in importance. Editing is changing/correcting the OP's "words".

Comment: I agree that the description is important and that this one was bad. But I don't agree with the general rule that you need to mention that you added a tag. That much is obvious from the preview. It's like comments in code: don't explain *what* the code does, explain ***why***.

Comment: @CodyGray, I agree with you that explaining "why" a tag was removed and another added is important. Added that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have stumbled across [someone who simply rejects pretty much every edits he sees](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228152/danodonovan?tab=activity&sort=reviews) . Mostly going against other reviewers decisions.

Also, make sure your edit description explains exactly what you edited.

I would have accepted your edit but it's my opinion.

Comment: The place to look is [on the very page he links to in the question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2584815). You'll need to click the "(more)" link, but it'll give you a detailed breakdown of states for each reviewer. In this case, danodonovan has approved 348 suggestions, and rejected 358. But be careful holding that against him: a lot of people click that "Approve" button *way* too easily.

Comment: True. But still. I looked at the last pages of his reviews and *checked* them. (Not the stats but the reviews themselves) and plenty are rejected for no valid reasons.