# Is correcting several minor spelling mistakes considered a substantial edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, spelling

I was about to edit the answer Christian Kuetbach gave in: [Does force close of a Java application cause Database connection leakage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560558/does-force-close-of-a-java-application-cause-database-connection-leakage)

The answer and its style were not bad, having only minor mistakes/slips, but in sum more than the needed six characters to make an edit. That would be:

- "withiin" (additional i)
- "ressources" (French spelling instead of English)
- twice a comma before "because"
- "Database" (capital letter in the middle of the sentence)
- "bonnection" (instead of connection)

I wouldn't have considered an edit for the first four points. But "bonnection" just leaps to the eye. So I don't know if I'm here just nitpicking or if those tiny one-letter corrections altogether justify an edit.

As Cody Gray pointed out in his [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186987/definitive-line-between-minor-and-substantial-edits), there isn't a really good answer to this question. So I'm rather asking for the gut feeling of the community how should I handle such (rather rare) cases in the future.

Comment: I would usually reject an edit if it is jut some trivial spelling errors. The only exception is when keywords are affected, because those are terms which are used for searching. i.E. if the title says something like "How to do this in Exclipse" instead of "Eclipse".

Comment: Did you fix all the problems with the post? Yes? Then IMO it's absolutely fine.

Comment: Matter of opinion I think. In the above example, that many typos would certainly warrant an edit. Or even fewer typos if they're in the post title. And I usually reject edits that cause horizontal scrollbars to appear in the post where there were none. But others may feel free to disagree.

Comment: Side note: Be careful with the "comma before because" case. Sometimes it's there [for a reason](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/5-calls-for-a-comma-before-%E2%80%9Cbecause%E2%80%9D/).

Comment: @GenericHolidayName: I knew that it's not always wrong. But after reading your link I was more confused than before and wasn't sure at all any more :) Anyway, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The six character limit is there to prevent trivial edits from unnecessarily taking up reviewers' time.  If you are changing enough legitimate errors to exceed 6 characters, then you have met that metric, and your suggested edit can therefore be thrown into the lion's den... er, review queue, for evaluation.

Fixing spelling and grammatical errors is a perfectly legitimate use of the edit system.  Remember, the audience for SE questions is the entire internet (or at least those folks interested in the subject matter), not just script kiddies who believe that *txtspk* is a legitimate form of the English language.  It is therefore  in our best interest to make questions and answers look professional.