# Can't find the option to edit tag wiki

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I want to edit a tag wiki but there is not any option to edit on the tag. Why?

[image]

Why are only a few options showing?

Comment: I can't see the issue in my system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are currently banned from suggesting edits due to having too many of your suggestions rejected. It clears in 5 days. Until then, you also cannot suggest edits on tag wikis or their excerpts.

Since tag wikis are slightly different in display (it shows a big black "Edit Tag Wiki" button rather than a normal edit link), the edit button just doesn't show up when you're not allowed to do so.

Comment: Case in point, your suggested edit here,@Shrawan , just made some words that didn't need to be italic italic and **introduced** a gramatical mistake. Try to make suggested edits bigger (and better) than that or not at all

Answer (score 3):

As animuson notes, you been temporarily banned from suggesting edits. While waiting for the ban to clear, you may want to take a look at [your past edit suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3164777/shrawan?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and see *why* they have been rejected.

From what I see at a glance, your biggest issue seems to be that you've been making a lot of small formatting edits that not only don't substantially improve the post, but it's not always even clear if they improve it *at all*.

In particular, please keep in mind that:

- In correct English typography, there should *not* be a space before punctuation like `:`, `?` or `!`.  Edits that add such spaces are simply incorrect.
- *Italics* and **bold text** should be used very sparingly, if at all.  (I probably over-use them myself.)  When editing a post, please don't add them unless it's *really* necessary to communicate the intended meaning of the original poster.
- The same goes for `code markup`, which should be used *only* for actual pieces of literal code embedded in text.  In particular, it generally should *not* be used for common English words like "array" that just happen to match a programming language keyword.
- Finally, [suggested edits should be substantial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186987/definitive-line-between-minor-and-substantial-edits) to avoid wasting the time of reviewers and to avoid needlessly bumping posts to the front page.  If the *only* corrections you'd like to make to a post are minor spelling or formatting changes like those discussed above, you should generally just leave it alone.  See [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) for more information.

For example, compare [this edit of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1101671) (which somehow got approved(!) despited introducing a random "`*emphasized text*`" snippet into the post) with [the followup edit by Uooo](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21253505/revisions) that *actually* improved the post's formatting substantially (and reverted most of your gratuitous formatting changes, too).  Mind you, I wouldn't necessarily call Uooo's edit *perfect* either, but at least it left the post looking significantly better than it was before.